# Optimise query to return various Nth percentiles in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I have a dataset that contains the execution time for various api calls.
What I am trying to do is return a table that provides the execution time for various percentiles across different api calls.
For context, I am doing this in Domo, which means I am using MySQL 5.6.

Example of data:

| Action | executionTime |
| --- | --- |
| call_x | 100 |
| call_x | 120 |
| call_x | 110 |
| call_y | 300 |
| call_y | 200 |
| call_y | 100 |

Expected Return:

| Action | Median | 90th Perc | 95th Perc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| call_x | 110 | 120 | 120 |
| call_y | 200 | 300 | 300 |

I have a solution that works, however it is quite slow over.
I'm not sure how much memory Domo throws at an SQL dataflow however, I would like to optimise my query as much as possible.
My solution is based on the one described here https://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2008/07/calculating-nth-percentile-in-mysql.html

```
SELECT
    action,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(executionTimeMillis ORDER BY 
    executionTimeMillis SEPARATOR ','), ',', 99/100 * COUNT(*) + 1), ',', -1) AS DECIMAL) 
    AS 99percentile,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(executionTimeMillis` ORDER BY 
    executionTimeMillis SEPARATOR ','), ',', 95/100 * COUNT(*) + 1), ',', -1) AS DECIMAL) 
    AS 95percentile,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(executionTimeMillis ORDER BY 
    executionTimeMillis SEPARATOR ','), ',', 90/100 * COUNT(*) + 1), ',', -1) AS DECIMAL) 
    AS 90percentile,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(executionTimeMillis ORDER BY 
    executionTimeMillis SEPARATOR ','), ',', 50/100 * COUNT(*) + 1), ',', -1) AS DECIMAL) 
    AS median,
    AVG(executionTimeMillis) AS mean,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(executionTimeMillis ORDER BY 
    executionTimeMillis SEPARATOR ','), ',', 25/100 * COUNT(*) + 1), ',', -1) AS DECIMAL) 
    AS 1quartile
FROM MY_TABLE GROUP BY action
```

I suspect the inefficiency comes from repeatedly creating a list of ordered execution times:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(executionTimeMillis` ORDER BY executionTimeMillis SEPARATOR ',')
```

However, as I am using MySQL 5.6 I don't have the option to use a CTE for that.

What else can I do to improve the efficiency of this query? Up to and including scrapping the whole thing and starting again.

Comment: Most places that use a CTE can use a nested SELECT query instead, as long the CTE is not recursive. But 5.6 is stupid old. It doesn't even really qualify as a modern database anymore, and that's not just in reference to the 2013 release date. MySQL kind of stagnated for a while starting around 2008, because Sun couldn't afford to advance the product near the end. So you're really looking at a 2007-era platform. Updating this system would be a good idea.

Comment: a CTE wouldn't make this any faster the percentile from Mysql 8 would